# Webview android using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

Hi i have make this for Robotium this is url:

> http://www.monetizziamo.com/eadv.html

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview);
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Button myView = solo.getView(Button.class, 0);
solo.waitForView(myView, 20, false);
solo.clickOnView(myView);
WebView view = solo.getView(WebView.class, 0);
solo.waitForView(view, 100000, false);
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("gbqfb"));

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: this not work crash whit my app